# BinaryTree preOrder iteration without using stack

Tags: binary-tree, preorder

Is there a way to preOrder iterate over a binaryTree without using stack or list?

recursive or not it doesnt matter ...

I just searched in the internet and I couldnt find any code doing such thing.

**Note:** Just save the values in array and not to print them out to the screen.

Comment: well actually the canonical preorder (and any -order except level-order) is done recursively, it's awesome how you were able to find a stack-based solution prior to recursive one

Comment: do you have a recursive solution?

Comment: A video explaining preorder traversal without using stack and recursion https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ChGER8A3Ps